How do I add more than one app/content in a Oqtane project using 2sxc?
So I am busy setting up a project using Oqtane and 2sxc but the current problem is that when I add a second app or content, it cause error with the project rendering but only works as intended when only have 1 app or content then I get the below console error in google chrome browser
I am at my wits end on how to resovle the above issue
If any more information is needed, I will provide if needed

What version of Oqtane? What version of 2sxc? Are you using one of the 2sxc apps like The Content App? If yes, what version is it?

If your 2sxc is not the latest version, I recommend upgrading. There were some fixes in v18.02.00 that were related to content, inner content and possibly specific to Oqtane.

I was using v18.00.00. I will update and revert asap

Please do try the latest 18.02 and if the problem persists, open an issue.

@JuanduToit, if the upgrade worked for you, would you please accept this answer? Thank you in advance! - Jeremy
